# CSS - Move border closer to text

Tags: html, css, border

I have link that I want a border around but I can't get the border to appear closer to the text. Below is the css for the element;

```
.signup{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;}
```

which displays the border as;

[image]

If I add `height: 1.2em` it reduces the bottom spacing but not the top;

[image: image 2]

how do I reduce the spacing above the text?

I'm using the bootstrap flatly theme http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ the element I want the border around is 'WrapBootstrap' in the top right of the navigation bar.

Comment: Do you have fiddle or demo?

Comment: Show some css and html please. or add it to jsfiddle.net

Comment: It can be many factors then, and it's hard to help you without real example. Try padding though.

Comment: Please try adjusting the line-height

Answer (score 1):

You should give the `border` style to the `<span>` itself.

```
span{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Editing the `padding` will allow you to move the border from the text.

In your case the `position` of the `<span>` and the `.margin` might be causing the discrepancy. Like @dfsq pointed out, there could be other factors.

Comment: what span do you mean?

Comment: The container of the "Sign Up" text. It should ideally be a `<span>`

Comment: Could be a button or anchor, plus padding doesn't work on inline elements, you would have to make it inline-block

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what you're talking about. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/0u1k66jo/